# Delete a row in pandas given a conditions data cleansing?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame like

```
Classification     Value_1      Value_2       
churn                 1.0            2.0             
not_churn             2.0            3.0
not_churn             0.0            0.0
churn                 0.0            1.0
```

I know that with all values = 0, the classification should be churn. Then I need to delete all the rows with all values is 0 and classification is not_churn. I tried:

```
 df.drop((df['value_1'] == 0 
              & df['value_2'] == 0
              & df['classification']== 'not_churn').index)
'TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with change conditions for not equal `!=` and change `&` to `|` (or):

```
df = df[(df['Value_1'] != 0 ) | (df['Value_2'] != 0) | (df['Classification'] != 'not_churn')]
print (df)
  Classification  Value_1  Value_2
0          churn      1.0      2.0
1      not_churn      2.0      3.0
3          churn      0.0      1.0
```

Comment: Thank you but I got this error `Series' object is not callable`

Comment: @Homesand - Weird error, maybe help restart yout IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep rows according to what you don't want, I would try:

```
  df = df[~((df['value_1'] == 0) & (df['value_2'] == 0) & (df['classification'] == 'not churn'))]
```